# Symfony2 & Apache2 : Can't load the app_dev.php file

Tags: apache, symfony, ubuntu

I want to configure a Symfony2 for a school project and I can't access the test page as they do in the sensiolab tutorial (here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html). I work on a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 4.8.2. I installed symfony2 and apache2, I configured both on my VM but I still can't access my site.

So I tried to import my project on windows and when I test it with WAMP it works well. So, I don't understand why I can't access it from Ubuntu.

Here is my config on apache :

[image: site available config]

And here is what the browser display :

> unregister(); $apcLoader->register(true); */ $kernel = new
>   AppKernel('prod', false); $kernel->loadClassCache(); //$kernel = new
>   AppCache($kernel); // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the
>   method in your front controller instead of relying on the
>   configuration parameter
>   //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride(); $request =
>   Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request);
>   $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

It's a part of the app.php file.

What should I need to do to access my site from Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows the routes changes :

```
DocumentRoot /home/gaetan/RailCommander/web
```

should be somethin like :

```
DocumentRoot "C:/route_to_your_web"
```

But dont forget de drive unit letter in all of your apache routes in windows

Comment: The route DocumentRoot /home/gaetan/RailCommander/web is the route where my project is on my VM Ubuntu.